# Does anyone know a good way to handle z ordering when using GraphicTracker in ArcEngine?

Tags: arcobjects

From the [GraphicTracker Documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000004tv000000):

> The first graphic added will appear
>   underneath subsequent graphics if they
>   have overlapping display areas.

This is not true when using ArcEngine 10.0 with polygon fill symbols on picture marker symbols - sometimes it works (1st time for sure) and sometimes it does not.

Has anyone figured out a proper way to manage z ordering of symbols when using ArcEngine and using GraphicTracker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESRI gave me the correct answer to this - you need to manage ordering use the multiple instances of the GraphicTracker - any subsequent GraphicTracker will have its graphics overlap over any previous instance of GraphicTracker's graphics.  There is no guarantee of ordering of graphics within a single instance of a GraphicTracker instance.